# Where clause in mysql not working

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I am working on a project using php codeigniter,i am using mysql select query to fetch all data from database where isactive field is equal to 1.but i am unable to do it.below is the function where i have writtten the query.

Code:

```
public function displayinfo3()
        {
            $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
            if($user_id)
            {
                $this->load->library('datatables');
                $this->datatables
                                    ->select("user_type.user_type as user_type,user.user_name as user_name,user.first_name as first_name,user.middle_name as middle_name,user.last_name as last_name,user.user_id as Actions")
                            ->from("user")
                            ->where('isactive'==1)
                                                    ->join("user_type","user_type.user_type_id=user.user_type_id","left")
                            ->edit_column("Actions", 
                                                            "<center><div class='visible-md visible-lg hidden-sm hidden-xs'><div align='center'><div class='col-md-2'><form action='".base_url()."index.php/Registrationc/editpatient3' method='post'><input type='hidden' id='editp3' name='editp3' value='$1'><button title='EDIT PATIENT' class='tip btn btn-primary btn-xs' type='submit' value='Submit' ><i class='fa fa-edit'></i></button></form></div><div class='col-md-2'><a class=\"tip btn btn-danger btn-xs\" title='DELETE PATIENT' href='#' onclick=\"delete_patient('$1')\" ><i class=\"fa fa-trash-o\"></i></a></div></div></div></center>", "Actions");
                                                    // $this->datatables->unset_column('Sno.patient_id');<form action=""><div class='btn-group'>
                                       //<a class=\"tip btn btn-primary btn-xs\" onclick=\"edit_patient('$1')\" title='EDIT MAPPING' href='#' return false;\"><i class=\"fa fa-edit\"></i></a>                         
                            echo $this->datatables->generate();
             }
            else
            {
                redirect(base_url('Registrationc/extra1'));
            }  


}
```

Comment: `->where('isactive'==1)` there's one equal sign too many.

Comment: Wouldn't it be `->where('isactive = 1')`?  Otherwise `'isactive'==1` is going to be evaluated in PHP and just send a boolean to the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `->where('isactive'==1)` with `->where('isactive = 1')`

The first passes the result of the comparison of `'isactive'` with `1` to the function. As `'isactive'` is not equal to `1` you just pass a false value to your where statement.

The second call passes the correct query string to be put in the where statement of the query.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the `->where('isactive'==1)` to `->where('isactive = 1')` and returns a bool result.